# Kmap and boolean equation for a function

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

```
F(A,B,C,D) = Σm(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15)
```

Here's my try of the kmap:

[image]

Are my kmap and boolean equation correct for this function?

Comment: That looks like a k-map and a boolean expression that match each other. Is that all you are asking about?

Comment: @jonk i know this is too basic but i just wanted to make sure if i have made the correct kmap according to the function. 
thanks!

Comment: Okay. Well, it looks good to me. The boolean logic isn't the only possible minimized version. There's at least one other. But it looks okay, as is, to me.

Comment: It's minimized is what @jonk is trying to say!

Comment: @user326829 No problem. You got it right. What can I say? It's your work. You might take a clue and see if you can come up with the 2nd way of saying the same thing using a different minimized combination. Just to see that the same kmap can produce alternate, equally minimized algebra. Other than that, you are just fine I think!

Comment: Possibly use of an XOR function (?).